# How to change the bar color of FL_HOR_NICE_SLIDER in fltk?

Tags: fltk

I want to change the bar color of FL_HOR_NICE_SLIDER to green, so I tried the following code:

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Slider.H>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Fl::scheme("GTK+");

    Fl::background(50, 50, 50);
    Fl::background2(90, 90, 90);
    Fl::foreground(255, 255, 255);

    Fl_Window *window = new Fl_Window(400, 60);

    Fl_Slider *slider = new Fl_Slider(20, 20, 300, 20);
    slider->type(FL_HOR_NICE_SLIDER);
    slider->box(FL_FLAT_BOX);
    slider->color(0x00DD0000);
    slider->color2(0xDDDDDD00);

    window->end();
    window->show(argc, argv);
    return Fl::run();
}
```

The result of this code is shown below. The bar color remains white, but the "area" color changes to green, which is not my desired result.

[image: incorrect result]

What I would like to achieve is the following result:

[image: expected result]

(I use `Fl::foreground(0, 255, 0);` and delete `slider->color(0x00DD0000);` to get the result above, but I don't want to change the foreground color because this will change other colors as well, for example the default font color).

How can I achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking out the source code of fltk, I disappointedly discovered that I can only change the bar color by changing the foreground color.

The source code of drawing the bar of FL_HOR_NICE_SLIDER is shown below:

```
void Fl_Slider::draw_bg(int X, int Y, int W, int H) {
  fl_push_clip(X, Y, W, H);
  draw_box();
  fl_pop_clip();

  Fl_Color black = active_r() ? FL_FOREGROUND_COLOR : FL_INACTIVE_COLOR;
  if (type() == FL_VERT_NICE_SLIDER) {
    draw_box(FL_THIN_DOWN_BOX, X+W/2-2, Y, 4, H, black);
  } else if (type() == FL_HOR_NICE_SLIDER) {
    draw_box(FL_THIN_DOWN_BOX, X, Y+H/2-2, W, 4, black);
  }
}
```

Note that the color is either `FL_FOREGROUND_COLOR` or `FL_INACTIVE_COLOR`, depending on whether the slider is active or not.

Comment: Of course, one can always inherit the slider class and write his own slider, but this is somewhat complex.

Comment: If you are writing an inherited slider,with a slider_color member,  you will need to change the draw_bg in Fl_slider to a protected function and rebuild the library.  If the library is not rebuilt, the override will not happen.

Comment: It's ok not to rebuild the library. I wrote an inherited slider, override the draw method, and wrote my own draw_bg method (this new draw_bg method is called in the overridden draw method).